# Is it possible to only allow one account to query on a BigQuery Project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Basically, we want a setup that will allow only one service account (that we intend to use for production use-cases) to run queries on a particular project. No other account should be able to run queries.

Is this possible? How can we go about doing this?

Comment: The admin and the owner of the project will always be able to access the data. But yes,the IAM let define the rights to a service account very detailed.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please add more details such as standalone project, organization, etc. Are you trying to prevent any account from gaining access in the future or are you trying to define one account with access at this point in time? Details matter to get a good answer as the are several possible configurations.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create the service account and gives it all the needed privileges to run queries on this particular project.

You also have to check that no other service account has privileges allowing to perform query on this project.

With IAM you have all the flexibility to do that, and with the `least privilege` concept, you can create a custom role on `IAM` and give only the needed permissions to your Service Account.